# Use protocols as argument type in Swift 4.1 with Xcode 9.3

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

So I have an enum type:

```
enum ObjectType {
   case encodable(Encodable)
   case data(Data)
   case string(String)
}
```

and a function:

```
func setObject<T: Encodable>(_ obj: T) {
    self.body = try? JSONEncoder().encode(obj)
}
```

then I got an error when I was doing this:

```
switch type {
case .encodable(let e):
    setObject(e) // e: Encodable
default: break
}
```

> `Cannot convert value of type 'Encodable' to expected argument type '_?'`

Comment: Generics need a concrete type to be fullfilled with, and protocols are incomplete types.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your enum to be generic.

```
enum ObjectType<E: Encodable> {
    case encodable(E)
    case data(Data)
    case string(String)
}
```

The issue is that the underlying type of your enum is `Encodable`, so what gets passed to `JSONEncoder.encode` isn't an object whose type conforms to the protocol, but rather its type *is* the protocol. It's a subtle difference that I don't really understand ‍♂️